# How to fix mariadb replication: Could not execute Delete_rows_v1 event on table db.tableName; Index for table './db/tableName.MYI'

Tags: mariadb, replication

We have 2 mariadb servers in replication (master-slave). Those 2 servers were turn off unexpectedly. When mariadb servers get online myisam tables were checked on db1 and db2:

```
|  85 | db          | ip:55336 | db | Query       | 4398 | Checking table                                                        | tableName |    0.000 |
```

I have changed a slave to read master binary log from new file and new position (I think there was no lag on replication) but when I start slave on db2 I got replication error:

```
Could not execute Delete_rows_v1 event on table db.tableName; Index for table './db/tableName.MYI' is corrupt; try to repair it, Error_code: 126; handler error HA_ERR_WRONG_IN_RECORD; the event's master log binlog-file-01, end_log_pos 8980
```

Can you help me how can I fix it?
we deleted all rows in db1 for this table. Should I remove all rows for this table on db2? and then skip all steps in replication which are connected with that? there was lot of this rows.

Additionally:

On DB2:
**Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 810**

When I read event logs for this file on db1:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW BINLOG EVENTS IN 'binlog-file-01' from 810 limit 5;
+---------------------------+------+----------------+-----------+-------------+------------------------------------------------+
| Log_name                  | Pos  | Event_type     | Server_id | End_log_pos | Info                                           |
+---------------------------+------+----------------+-----------+-------------+------------------------------------------------+
| binlog-file-01 |  810 | Gtid           |         1 |         852 | BEGIN GTID 0-1-5630806796                      |
| binlog-file-01 |  852 | Annotate_rows  |         1 |         908 | DELETE FROM tableName              |
| binlog-file-01 |  908 | Table_map      |         1 |         993 | table_id: 107 (db.tableName) |
| binlog-file-01 |  993 | Delete_rows_v1 |         1 |        8980 | table_id: 107                                  |
| binlog-file-01 | 8980 | Delete_rows_v1 |         1 |       17006 | table_id: 107                                  |
+---------------------------+------+----------------+-----------+-------------+------------------------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Can I just skip this on replication?

Answer (score 0):

`./db/tableName.MYI` indicates a corrupt index. If `check table db.tableName` didn't resolve this you can try:

- drop and recreate the indexes on this table on the replica
- `truncate table tableName` (as the binary log appears to be a `delete from tableName` without a where clause.

If the replication still fails on this binary log entry you can skip it with:

```
SET GLOBAL sql_slave_skip_counter=1
```

reference: [ref](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/replication-and-binary-log-system-variables/#sql_slave_skip_counter).

Recommend changing your MyISAM tables to Aria or InnoDB to be crash safe in the case of power failure. Also set [sync_binlog=1](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/replication-and-binary-log-system-variables/#sync_binlog) for persistent safety.